How do I solve a conflict of gradle tasks between 2 gradle plugins?
I have a multi-module gradle project and I want to use gradle-cobertura-plugin on my root project:
apply plugin: 'net.saliman.cobertura'

This adds, in particular, the task clean from the cobertura plugin.
The issue is, there is another apply plugin that I cannot remove, which also adds a task named clean.
When I try to launch gradle cobertura, it raises this error:
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'root-project'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'cobertura']
   > Failed to apply plugin [class 'org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LifecycleBasePlugin']
      > Cannot add task ':clean' as a task with that name already exists.


A frustrating one
This is a frustrating one, because there would appear to be no smooth way of dealing with such a name clash across plugins in the same project. Tasks cannot be renamed, and there is no namespacing solution.
I suppose in practice a single Gradle project does not in general have different plugins added doing the same thing, especially with the availability of multi-module and included builds, and so no such features has been found to be necessary by the team.
Your issue
The clean task from the Corbetura plugin is not added by that plugin per se, but more specifically the Corbetura plugin is applying the Gradle LifecycleBasePlugin which adds the standard Gradle tasks clean, build, check and assemble. Using that plugin is about as standard as it gets for Gradle builds. Given that convention, then I venture that the writer of the other plugin should have a compelling reason to go against it and write their own clean task.
As clean is added from a specific plugin that may not be needed, it's tempting to try and intercept and alter the application of that plugin, since there is a way1 of doing just that. Unfortunately, however, that appears to only work with plugins applied in a plugins block and not, as here, plugins applied by another plugin.
Possible solutions
Given the restrictions on you, I would suggest you reconsider if it's possible to apply the plugins in different subprojects.
If that's not possible, I think you need to take a cruder approach and essentially write your own code to cherry-pick the the parts of one of the plugins in such a way that it consistently renames the clean method in that plugin, or ensures that it is never added at all, if you don't need it.
To do that, you could write your own plugin which has the JAR of one of your two clashing plugins as a dependency, and then you call the relevant parts of that plugin from within the apply method of your own plugin. You would then apply your own plugin instead of the dependent plugin.

1 pluginManagement.resolutionStrategy.eachPlugin in the settings file
